# Does anyone have examples of how to store the facebook login in android?

Tags: android, facebook

I need to store the login to facebook, but I need to repeatedly calling authorize. Does anyone have examples on how to store this so I don't have to authorize everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the facebook github. They have this demo:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/simple/src/com/facebook/android/SessionStore.java

It lets you save and restore sessions from the context shared preferences.